# Is there a way to set a property value to the formatted install date/time

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Is there a way to set a property value to the formatted install date/time?

I'm in the process of creating an MSI installer for an old VB6 application we still depend on (yes, I know, upgrade before it dies).

I'm trying to add a backup folder for the user data files in the install-folder (not my application design, nor my application). Unfortunately every user of this application has their own copy of the data file installed on their system (dedicated machines per user), and the installer has the default file. I would like to create a backup folder so that I can manually (if necessary) go back and retrieve previous versions of the file.

What I'm thinking is 
c:\program files (x86)\app*.mdb => c:\program files (x86)\app\backups\201804091125

Answer (score 0):

This will be rushed. Please tell me what is not clear.

***Custom Action***: In order to implement exactly what you describe, you generally need a custom action. This is always unfortunate since they are very error prone: [Why is it a good idea to limit the use of custom actions in my WiX / MSI setups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779)

***Alternative?***: If you ask me I would install the database in a component of its own, make the file the key file and set the component to **permanent** and **never overwrite if key path exists**.

In the WiX source: for the WiX component element, set these attributes: `Permanent="yes" NeverOverwrite="yes"`). I am not 100% sure what will happen if you do something stupid such as setting `REINSTALLMODE="amus"` during installation (force overwrite all files regardless of version). It has been a while since I tested the `NeverOverwrite` flag. But for normal deployment done the regular way the database file should be left alone and not overwritten.

---

***Custom Action Overview***: There are properties called [Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372079(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that are automatically set in the installer, but the `Date` property will generally contain characters that are illegal in path names. It is possible to just get the properties and replace the illegal characters. However, the date separation characters are probably different based on regional settings and hence hard to predict. Your code could get messy quickly and testing would be challenging (potentially many locales to test depending on distribution scope - a truly globally capable package is challenging).

I would rather get the date and time some other way - via some programming API call where I can determine what format the data comes back in. You also need to run this custom action elevated in deferred mode to ensure it doesn't fall over with access denied (insufficient user rights for operation). This is always quite a bit of clunk to set up and get working. Maybe try the alternative approach first?

I have long considered adding a custom action to abort the install if `REINSTALLMODE="amus"` has been specified. I would prefer that and the alternative approach described with "never overwrite" to a custom action doing all this copying.