# WixToolset custom actions and packagereference not working

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action, wix3.11

I hope someone can help me on this one. I am using a couple of custom actions inside my installer. A couple of these custom actions rely on other projects within my solution (some common stuff). Ever since I moved these projects from package.config to packagereferences it seems that all packages that are indirectly referenced by my project (i.e. the dependencies of the dependencies my projects have), do not endup in my CA.dll.

Anyone have any experience on how to get this back in?

Comment: Can we ask what the custom actions do?

Comment: Sorry, let me add why we ask: very often you can find built-in MSI ways to do the same as you do with custom actions, or there are WiX-specific constructs that can be used instead - and this is always more reliable. Behold! [Propaganda against custom actions!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179779/129130) :-).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, there are several things being done inside the custom actions; amongst others the creation of some databases on a different machine. If there is a default WiX / MSI way to do so that would be also great. On the other hand that doesn’t satisfy my curiosity of why this is not working this way :-)